# How labelling works in image segmentation [SegNet]

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am trying to understand image segmentation using SegNet implementation in keras. I have read the original paper using the Conv and Deconv architechture and also using the Dilated conv layers. However, I have trouble understanding how the labelling of the pixel works.

I am considering the following implementation:
https://github.com/nicolov/segmentation_keras

Here the pascal dataset attributes are used:

21 Classes:

```
# 0=background
# 1=aeroplane, 2=bicycle, 3=bird, 4=boat, 5=bottle
# 6=bus, 7=car, 8=cat, 9=chair, 10=cow
# 11=diningtable, 12=dog, 13=horse, 14=motorbike, 15=person
# 16=potted plant, 17=sheep, 18=sofa, 19=train, 20=tv/monitor
```

The classes are represented by:

```python
pascal_nclasses = 21
pascal_palette = np.array([(0, 0, 0)
    , (128, 0, 0), (0, 128, 0), (128, 128, 0), (0, 0, 128), (128, 0, 128)
    , (0, 128, 128), (128, 128, 128), (64, 0, 0), (192, 0, 0), (64, 128, 0)
    , (192, 128, 0), (64, 0, 128), (192, 0, 128), (64, 128, 128), (192, 128, 128)
    , (0, 64, 0), (128, 64, 0), (0, 192, 0), (128, 192, 0), (0, 64, 128)], dtype=np.uint8)
```

I was trying to open the labelled images for cat and boat, as cat is in only in R space and boat only in blue. I used following to show the labelled images:

For boat:

```python
label = cv2.imread("2008_000120.png")
label = np.multiply(label, 100)
cv2.imshow("kk", label[:,:,2])
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For cat:

```python
label = cv2.imread("2008_000056.png")
label = np.multiply(label, 100)
cv2.imshow("kk", label[:,:,0])
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However, it doesnt matter which space I choose both images always gives same results. i.e. the following code also gives same results

For boat:

```python
label = cv2.imread("2008_000120.png")
label = np.multiply(label, 100)
cv2.imshow("kk", label[:,:,1]) # changed to Green space
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For cat:

```python
label = cv2.imread("2008_000056.png")
label = np.multiply(label, 100)
cv2.imshow("kk", label[:,:,1]) # changed to Green space
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

My assumption was that I will see the cat only in Red color space and boat only in blue. However, the output in all cases:

[image: Masked boat]
[image: masked cat]

I am confused now how these pixels are labelled and how are they read and uniquely used to pair with categories in the process of creating the logits.

It will be great if someone can explain or put some relevant links to understand this process. I tried to search but most of the tutorials only discuss the CNN architecture, not the labelling process or how these labels are used within the CNN.

I have attached the labelled images of cat and boat for reference.
[image: Labelled boat]
[image: Labelled cat]

Answer (score 3):

The labels are just binary image masks so single channel images. The pixel value at each location of your label image changes depending on the class present at each pixel. So it will be value 0 when there is no object at a pixel and a value 1-20 depending on the class otherwise.

Semantic segmentation is a classification task so you are trying to classify each pixel with a class ( in this case class labels 0-20).

Your model will produce an output image and you want to perform softmax cross entropy between each output image pixel and each label image pixel.

In the multiclass case where you have K classes (like here K=21) each pixel will have K channels and you perform softmax cross entropy across the channels at each pixel. Why a channel for each class? Think about in classification we produce a vector of length K for K classes and this is compared to a one hot vector of length K.